# How Can I Make 1 / 3 = 0.3 ? Eclipse, java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to make a program for my School homework.

it told me to divide 1 with 3, and get a result:

Quotient = 0.3

Remainder = 0.1

I've tried to use double ( result from the quotient = 0,33333333) and int ( result from the quotient = 0).

Is it possible to make such a program? Thank you.

Comment: try to use Modulus

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to make such a program.

The main idea behind this program is to simulate the same way you'd do it if you were doing the division by hand on paper.  Don't go looking for a simple, single math function to do this.  It is a problem that's been asked this way on purpose to guarantee there's not a single type of division operator which will give you the correct answer.

Hint: remember that dividing is performed by subtracting values, shifted in places.  So `1.0` is "divided by" `0.3` by `1.0 - 3*0.3`, leaving a remainder of `0.1`

Comment: Thank you very much! you've just opened my mind! it's working now :)